# Should we say birchas ha-torah before each Passover seder?

Tags: halacha, passover-seder-hagada, birchos-hatorah

Why not precede or start the Passover seder with birchas ha-torah? Is the content of the Passover Seder material that should be preceded by birchas ha-torah?  If so, why is birchas ha-torah not in the Hagada, especially nowadays when many (most) do not say this bracha in the morning?  If not, why?

Comment: Please explain your assumption for "nowadays when many (most) do not say this bracha in the morning". It's in the Siddur.

Comment: What do you mean? That because the seder is an activity that even non-religious Jews participate in, why do we not incorporate a bracha that they *should* be making every day as a precursor? Why not add Asher Yatzar? Or kriyas shema? Ayn ladavr sof...

Comment: It is in the Hagada ברוך המקום שנתן תורה לעמו ישראל

Comment: @Double AA  That seems relevant to my question.  Where does that appear?

Comment: @YehudaW It's from right before the 4 sons

Comment: @DoubleAA - Can you explain how that phrase is considered "Birkat Hatorah" - i.e. - it fulfills the same halachic requirement as the ones said in Shacharit?

Comment: @DanF although i disagree with the assumption in the question, double aa has a great point. That phrase should suffice for birchas HaTorah, at least bidieved, at least as much as birchas krias shma which we know does. Lulei mistafina I would say its there for all the kids who took naps erev yom tov! Mistafina, because we don't paskin like that:)

Comment: @DoubleAA sounds like an answer, with the addition of sources and/or halachic reasoning.

Comment: Why did 2 people not like the question?  I am new here.  Whose ox did I gore?

Comment: @YehudaW Probably in line with Danny's or Isaac K's comments.

Comment: @isaac-kotlicky  I do not really understand your reply.  I was asking about a bracha that is or may be thought to be related to the seder.  Your comment was on unrelated rituals or prayers.

Comment: @danny-schoemann  The seder is the most widely observed Jewish custom.  The proportion of Jews who daven shacharit pales in comparison.  I thought this so universally known that it did not need any explanation. Since your comment got 5 likes, I must be missing something.  Perhaps you might explain it to me. (As a newcomer here, I am still trying to figure out the psychology and sociology of the group.)

Comment: @YehudaW Birchas HaTorah has no more to do with the seder than any other bracha or ritual we do on a daily basis. Nominally, everyone would have already made the bracha as part of their morning obligations. Repeating it would be a bracha levatala. We do not create such a situation (normally a violation of established law) for observant people to accommodate those who don't observe halacha anyhow.

Comment: @YehudaW - I think you have 2 questions here: 1. Does the Hagodo require Birkat HaTorah, and 2. Why isn't it part of the Nussach.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17259/501

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 questions here.

**1. Why isn't Birkat HaTorah an integral part of the Hagada?**

The first question is easy to answer. At the time when the Hagada was redacted, ([about 1,800 years ago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haggadah#Authorship)), it was assumed that everybody followed Halacha, and had therefore already prayed Shacharit, which includes Birkat HaTorah.

But surely there were excpetions?

We already know what the Hagada's authors' thoughts are how to treat the wicked son. We don't accommodate him, we  make him feel unwelcome. (Apply this in the 21st century at your own risk.)

**2. Does one have to say Birkat HaTorah before the Hagada?**

It would seem from Hilchot Talmud Torah, [סימן מז - דיני ברכת התורה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_4.html#HtmpReportNum0001_L2) that somebody participating at a Seder - who doesn't actually speak any Torah - is exempt from Birkat HaTorah.

> **ד:** הַמְהַרְהֵר בְּדִבְרֵי תּוֹרָה, אֵין צָרִיךְ לְבָרֵךְ: הגה: וְה''ה דְּיָכוֹל לִפְסֹק דִּין בְּלֹא נְתִינַת טַעַם לִדְבָרָיו (רַ''ן פ''ק דְּשַׁבָּת וּפֶרֶק כָּל הַצְלָמִים כָּתַב דְּהָוֵי כְּהִרְהוּר). &רךצף

One who only thinks about Torah but doesn't say anything, does not need to first say Birkat HaTorah. One may even Pasken - without giving reasons - before Birkat HaTorah.

This is echoed in the  באר היטב  who comments on the previous Halacha (that one who writes Torah thoughts needs to say Birkat HaTorah) that the writer should be careful to say some Torah after making Birkat HaTorah.

> **ג:** הַכּוֹתֵב (**ב**) בְּדִבְרֵי תּוֹרָה, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵינוֹ קוֹרֵא, צָרִיךְ (**ג**) לְבָרֵךְ. ‏
>
> **באר היטב**  (**ב**) בד''ת. ודוקא בכותב ספרים לעצמו דרך לימודו ומבין מה שהוא כותב אבל סופר שמעתיק ספר ואינו מבקש להבין מה שהוא כותב א''צ לברך וה''ה אם כותב אגרת שלומים אף שכותב איזה פסוקים א''צ לברך. מ''א וט''ז: (**ג**) לברך. דהרהור לאו כדיבור דמי. לפי זה **יש ליזהר לאותן לומדים בעיון מתוך הספר שיזהרו להוציא קצת דברי תורה בפה אחר הברכה**: ‏

So it would seem that passive participants at a Seder would not have to say Birkat HaTorah.

Which leaves one with the leader of the Seder (and the more active participants).

This leads to the root of the question: When does one have to say Birkat HaTorah?

> **ב:** צָרִיךְ לְבָרֵךְ בֵּין לְמִקְרָא בֵּין לְמִשְׁנָה בֵּין לִגְמָרָא: **הגה**: בֵּין לְמִדְרָשׁ (טוּר).  ‏

The Shulchan Aruch says one need only say Birkat HaTorah for studying Torah (as in Bible), Mishna or Talmud (Gemara). The Remo adds Midrash.

Where does the Hagada fit in?

One could posit that since we're only story-telling, it's similar to the section of Birkat HaShachar - לְעוֹלָם יְהֵא אָדָם יְרֵא שָׁמַיִם בַּסֵּתֶר - that is said before Birkat HaTorah by some (including the Vilna Gaon, supposedly).

It's actually an argument in Shulchan Aruch  - [סימן מו - הלכות ברכות השחר](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_4.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2) - as to whether saying Psukim (as opposed to learning them) requires Birkat HaTorah.

> **ט:** לֹא יִקְרָא פְּסוּקִים קֹדֶם בִּרְכַּת הַתּוֹרָה, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא אוֹמְרָהּ דֶּרֶךְ תַּחֲנוּנִים. **וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁאֵין לָחוּשׁ, כֵּיוָן שֶׁאֵינוֹ אוֹמְרָם אֶלָּא דֶּרֶךְ תַּחֲנוּנִים**. וְנָכוֹן לָחוּשׁ לִסְבָרָא רִאשׁוֹנָה: הגה: אֲבָל הַ**מִּנְהָג כִּסְבָרָא אַחֲרוֹנָה**, שֶׁהֲרֵי בִּימֵי (**יג**) הַסְּלִיחוֹת מִתְפַּלְּלִין הַסְּלִיחוֹת וְאַחַר כָּךְ מְבָרְכִין עַל הַתּוֹרָה עִם סֵדֶר שְׁאָר הַבְּרָכוֹת, וְכֵן בְּכָל יוֹם כְּשֶׁנִּכְנָסִין לְבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת אוֹמְרִים כַּמָּה פְּסוּקִים וְתַחֲנוּנִים וְאַחַר כָּךְ מְבָרְכִין עַל הַתּוֹרָה, וְנָהֲגוּ לְסַדֵּר בִּרְכַּת הַתּוֹרָה מִיָּד אַחַר בִּרְכַּת אֲשֶׁר יָצַר וְאֵין לְשַׁנּוֹת. (וְכֵן מַשְׁמָע בְּתוס' וּמָרְדְּכַי פ''ק דִּבְרָכוֹת) וְטוֹב לוֹמַר בְּשַׁחֲרִית אַחַר שְׁמַע יִשְׂרָאֵל וְגו' בָּרוּךְ שֵׁם כְּבוֹד מַלְכוּתוֹ לְעוֹלָם וָעֶד, כִּי לִפְעָמִים שׁוֹהִין עִם קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע לִקְרוֹתָהּ שֶׁלֹּא בִּזְמַנָּהּ, (**יד**) וְיוֹצֵא בָּזֶה (טוּר): ‏
>
> **באר היטב**  (**יג**) הסליחות. עיין סימן תקפ''א מה שכתבנו שם: (**יד**) ויוצא בזה. אך לא יכוין לצאת אלא אם כן ירא שהציבור יעברו זמן קריאת שמע אבל כשלא יעברו מוטב לצאת ידי קריאת שמע עם הציבור ולקרות אותה כדינה בברכותיה ולסמוך גאולה לתפלה. ב''ח. רש''ל כתב לומר גם כן פרשה ראשונה: ‏

The Remo says that we always say Psukim before Birkat HaTorah. E.g. upon entering Shul we say מַה טֹּבוּ אֹהָלֶיךָ יַעֲקֹב - long before we get to Birkat HaTorah.

He also mentions Selichot which is recited before Birkat HaTorah, though the באר היטב points one to [סימן תקפ''א](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_34.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2) where he brings the Levush who says that one should say Birkat HaTorah before Selichot.

> עוד כתב לבוש שיאמר ברכת התורה קודם הסליחות ולדלגו אח''כ

I couldn't find any classic Halachic sources dealing with Birkat HaTorah and reciting the Hagada.

A Google search points to Rabbi Joseph B. Halevi Soloveitchik's *Shi'urim Lezekher Abba Mari z"l, vol.  II, pp.  156-163* as quoted in [this](http://etzion.org.il/vbm/english/alei/2-5seder.htm) essay:

> Mitzvat sippur yetzi'at Mitzrayim is actually a mitzvah of talmud Torah and mesorah.  This idea is accentuated by a passage, located towards the beginning of the Haggadah, whose wording has a striking resemblance to that of Birkat HaTorah - "בָּרוּךְ הַמָּקוֹם, בָּרוּךְ הוּא. בָּרוּךְ שֶׁנָּתַן תּוֹרָה לְעַמּוֹ יִשְׂרָאֵל, בָּרוּךְ הוּא"  Since sippur yetzi'at Mitzrayim is accomplished through talmud Torah, we understand why the Haggadah commences akin to Birkat HaTorah.